# Call a function with the value of another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The name of the function is stored in the value of another function and i need to call the function using the other function.

I need to call popup() function

```
random() = 'popup()'

if ($.cookie('optin-page')) {

}
```

i tried

```
if ($.cookie('optin-page')) {
    window[random()];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't assign a value to the return value of a function call. The left hand side of a statement with `=` in it cannot end in `()`. (i.e. the first line of your code is an error).

If you want to call a *global* function with a name that matches the return value of a function called `random` then you can:

```
window[random()]();
```

… but any time you are thinking about doing that, you should probably be storing those functions in an object and then calling them as methods of that object:

```
var foo = { 
    a: function () { 
        alert('e.g.'); 
    } 
};
function picker() { 
    return "a";
}
foo[picker()]();
```

Comment: im sorry, i forgot to say that the function returns that value. it is not directly assigned.

Comment: He's got the right idea of it. The string has to just be the function name, without the parentheses, like so: window["functionName"](arguments);

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off with a switch or something rather than just calling whatever string you get back...

```
var functionToCall = random();

switch(functionToCall)
{
case 'popup()':
    popup();
    break;
case 'function2()':
    function2();
    break;
default:
    // throw an error INVALID FUNCTION CALLED
}
```

This allows you to introduce error handling.